# Rearranging the formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Transpose this formula to make $y$ the subject.

$$x=\sqrt{x^2y^2+1-y}$$

My try:

$$x^2=x^2y^2+1-y$$

$$x^2-x^2y^2=1-y$$

$$x^2(1-y^2)=1-y$$

Here I got 2 $y$ terms, but I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: View it as a quadratic equation in $y$

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:**

$(1-y^2)=(1-y)(1+y)$

For $y\neq1$, ...

Answer (score 3):

You can write $$0=y^2-\frac{1}{x^2}y+\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}$$ using the quadratic formula we obtain
$$y_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2x^2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2-\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}}$$

Comment: That square root has the exact solution $\pm(1-\frac{1}{2x^2})$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see the factorization, treat the thing as a quadratic in $y$:
$$
x^2y^2-y+(1-x^2)=0
$$
The discriminant is
$$
1-4x^2(1-x^2)=4x^4-4x^2+1=(2x^2-1)^2
$$
Apply the quadratic formula:
$$
y=\frac{1\pm(2x^2-1)}{2x^2}
$$
and you find either $y=1$ or
$$
y=\frac{1-2x^2+1}{2x^2}=\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}
$$